# Bootstrap div element and nested navbar not taking up 100% page width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

There seems to be a bit of space between my navbar and the edge of the viewport. The navbar is nested in a div that is container-fluid, and I don't see where any padding or margin would be coming into play.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Nav -->
  <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark  navbar-expand-sm">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Generic</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Just put the `container-fluid` inside the Navbar, as shown in the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#containers

Comment: Damn - I must have read that page (and that section) 10 times over without understanding that. Thanks, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `padding` to `0` for your `container-fluid`